# Transform DateTime into simple Date in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have a datetime column in db that I want to transform into a simple date when I show it to users.

How can I do that?

```
def shown_date
  # to_date does not exist, but is what I am looking for
  self.date || self.exif_date_time_original.to_date 
end
```

Comment: Do you just want to format it?

Comment: No, I would like to create a Date object

Comment: Ooops.. stupid question! to_date DO EXISTS!

Sorry :(

Answer (score 186, accepted):

`DateTime#to_date` does exist with ActiveSupport:

```
$ irb
>> DateTime.new.to_date
NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_date' for #<DateTime: -1/2,0,2299161>
    from (irb):1

>> require 'active_support/core_ext'
=> true

>> DateTime.new.to_date
=> Mon, 01 Jan -4712
```

Comment: It's a shame that `.to_date()` is not present in standard ruby so we have to do workaround. Converting from DateTime to Date with correct timezone trough string (!!!) is not elegant. Understanding the internals of the DateTime and Date is not easy. Just rampaging, ignore! :-)

Comment: @Notinlist the entirety of rails is written in Ruby, so you could probably look on the rails api to find the to_date() method.  That will tell you the module it's in, which you could then include for DateTime objects in your code

Comment: .to_date was added in Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: @Michael you are incorrect. Here is the documentation for the standard library of Ruby 1.9.2 documenting the to_date function. http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-to_date

Answer (score 61):

Hello collimarco :) you can use ruby **strftime** method to create ur own date/time display.

*time.strftime( string ) => string*

```
  %a - The abbreviated weekday name (``Sun'')
  %A - The  full  weekday  name (``Sunday'')
  %b - The abbreviated month name (``Jan'')
  %B - The  full  month  name (``January'')
  %c - The preferred local date and time representation
  %d - Day of the month (01..31)
  %H - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock (00..23)
  %I - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock (01..12)
  %j - Day of the year (001..366)
  %m - Month of the year (01..12)
  %M - Minute of the hour (00..59)
  %p - Meridian indicator (``AM''  or  ``PM'')
  %S - Second of the minute (00..60)
  %U - Week  number  of the current year,
          starting with the first Sunday as the first
          day of the first week (00..53)
  %W - Week  number  of the current year,
          starting with the first Monday as the first
          day of the first week (00..53)
  %w - Day of the week (Sunday is 0, 0..6)
  %x - Preferred representation for the date alone, no time
  %X - Preferred representation for the time alone, no date
  %y - Year without a century (00..99)
  %Y - Year with century
  %Z - Time zone name
  %% - Literal ``%'' character

   t = Time.now
   t.strftime("Printed on %m/%d/%Y")   #=> "Printed on 04/09/2003"
   t.strftime("at %I:%M%p")            #=> "at 08:56AM"
```

Answer (score 23):

In Ruby 1.9.2 and above they added a .to_date function to DateTime:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-to_date

This instance method doesn't appear to be present in earlier versions like 1.8.7.

Comment: Only if you include active support as I detailed.

Comment: No, in Ruby 1.9.2 and above you don't need to include ActiveSupport. As you can see in my answer, I included a link to the core Ruby stdlib docs for 1.9.2.

Answer (score 4):

For old Ruby (1.8.x):

```
myDate = Date.parse(myDateTime.to_s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a gem to simplify this process and to neaten up your views, etc etc.

Check it out at: http://github.com/platform45/easy_dates

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the entry to a string first. As long as the database column type is a date it will be formated as a date.

self.date || self.exif_date_time_original.to_s

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using `DateTime.parse()` method
here is an example

```
time = 19-Jun-23 9:26:14 AM
date = DateTime.parse(time)
formatted_date = date.to_time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
time = date.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
datetime = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```