# What is the type for that input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a question that i cant figure out, if you can help me it will be great because I am really frustrated.

**i have this input:**  06/18/2011 17:45
in the model, which type i need to write so i can get it from the table easly... i get this output from a textfield...
 **Schema**

```
create_table "statuses", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.string   "group"
    t.datetime "date"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.date     "status_date"
end
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully understand your question. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Please rewrite your question with some more detail.  It's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite explained, but maybe this other question will get you thinking correctly.

[DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110411/transform-datetime-into-simple-date-in-ruby-on-rails)